# Moveup List with Definition list items

Tags: jquery, html

Recently Chris [posted an awesome jQuery code](http://css-tricks.com/the-moveup-menu/) on his Css-Tricks blog that allows a list to scroll up and down by mouse movement.  He used it for unordered list items though.

I would love to use this on my current client project, but I can't figure out how to use this on `<dt>` items

The HTML is this:

```
<dl>

            <dt><a href="#">Example.net</a></dt>
            <dd>
              1 dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.
            </dd>

            <dt><a href="#">Example2.net</a></dt>
            <dd>
              2 dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.
            </dd>

            <dt><a href="#">Example3.net</a></dt>
            <dd>
              3 dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.
            </dd>

            <dt><a href="#">Example4.net</a></dt>
            <dd>
              4 dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.
            </dd>
</dl>
```

`<dd>` is not below the `<dt>` items, its in another div placed by jQuery, so the `<dt>` of items is just lined up as links.

[image]

Also I am using the jQuery Plugin TinyScroll for the scrollbar, that sets the `overflow: autoflow;` or whatever. So that might be a reason that its not working for me.

But here is Chris Code from the blog post:

```
$("#menu").css("overflow", "hidden").wrapInner("<div id='mover' />");

var $el,
    speed = 13.5,    // needs to be manually tinkered with
    items = $("#menu a");

items
.each(function(i) {
        $(this).attr("data-pos", i);
})
.hover(function() {

        $el = $(this);
        $el.addClass("hover");  

        $("#mover").css("top", -($el.data("pos") * speed - 40));
        // 40 is the top padding for the fadeout

}, function() {
        $(this).removeClass("hover");
});
```

What would I have to change to get it working for me?

Comment: I wish I could have a bit more help

Comment: Instead of rewriting a new question, you can just edit this one.  It will get bumped back up to the front page to get more views.  If your new question is different enough that it will invalidate the existing answer, then you can just ask a new question without deleting this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/9uySK/ check this implementation.

you might have missed few things - position absolute on #mover element is one thing... but oh well - check the jsFiddle solution and if you have any questions just let me know and put them in the comments.

hope it helps,

Tom

ps. check the additions to the CSS as well

Comment: IT WORKS! Except when I hover the top jumps down... curates a large gap

Comment: you have to remove this -40 from movement calculation - but then it will produce bigger gap on the bottom - you'd have to add more calculations if you wanted it to stop at the top and bottom edges and don't scroll if the elements are visible and there isn't enough content to fill the scrolling area

Answer (score 0):

hide your `<dd>`s and use another container to hold their content

```
<div class="fancy-dl">
  <dl>
    ...
  </dl>
  <div class="displayer"></div>
</div>
```

and

```
$(function() {
  $('dd').hide();
  $('dt').hover(function() {
    var ddHtml = $(this).next('dd').html();
    $(this).parent().siblings('.displayer').hide().html(ddHtml).show();
  });
});
```

you may want to fade/animate the displayer rather than `hide` and `show`.

Comment: forgot to say: then your scrolling `<dl>` should be independent of the descriptions.

Comment: I don't get how i'm suppose to use this with the js I listed

Answer (score 0):

From the blog post http://css-tricks.com/the-moveup-menu/

Change:

```
items = $("#menu a");
```

to:

```
items = $("#menu dt");
```

and it should work with